# Java swing: Listening and repeating events from one frame in another

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, focus

i have 2 frames: *parent* and *child*. I want to do the following:
when parent frame gets activated or deiconified, child frame does the same thing.

```
private void attachListeners()
    {
        if (parentFrame != null)
        {
            parentFrame.addComponentListener(this);
            parentFrame.addWindowListener(new ViewEventAdapter(this));
        }
     @Override
        public void viewActivated()
        {            
            //  show it when the parent is activated
            if (!childFrame.isVisible())
            {  
                        childFrame.setVisible(true);
                        parentFrame.toFront();
            }
        }
```

But this causes infinite loop of flickering. If i remove toFront(), I cant switch focus to parent frame. I just need to somehow switch focus correctly.

Listener code:

```
    public class ViewEventAdapter implements WindowListener, InternalFrameListener
{
    private MyViewListener listener = null;


    public ViewEventAdapter(MiaViewListener inListener)
    {
        listener = inListener;
    }


    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent inE)
    {
        listener.viewActivated();
    }


    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent inE)
    {
        listener.viewClosed();
    }


    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent inE)
    {
        listener.viewClosing();
    }


    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent inE)
    {
        listener.viewDeactivated();
    }


    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent inE)
    {
        listener.viewDeiconified();
    }


    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent inE)
    {
        listener.viewIconified();
    }


    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent inE)
    {
        listener.viewOpened();
    }


    @Override
    public void internalFrameActivated(InternalFrameEvent inE)
    {
        listener.viewActivated();
    }


    @Override
    public void internalFrameClosed(InternalFrameEvent inE)
    {
        listener.viewClosed();
    }


    @Override
    public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent inE)
    {
        listener.viewClosing();
    }


    @Override
    public void internalFrameDeactivated(InternalFrameEvent inE)
    {
        listener.viewDeactivated();
    }


    @Override
    public void internalFrameDeiconified(InternalFrameEvent inE)
    {
        listener.viewDeiconified();
    }


    @Override
    public void internalFrameIconified(InternalFrameEvent inE)
    {
        listener.viewIconified();
    }


    @Override
    public void internalFrameOpened(InternalFrameEvent inE)
    {
        listener.viewOpened();
    }
}

public interface MyViewListener
{
    /**
     * Called when a view is activated
     */
    public void viewActivated();

    /**
     * Called when a view is closed
     */
    public void viewClosed();

    /**
     * Called when a view is closing
     */
    public void viewClosing();

    /**
     * Called when a view is deactivated
     */
    public void viewDeactivated();

    /**
     * Called when a view is deiconified
     */
    public void viewDeiconified();

    /**
     * Called when a view is iconified
     */
    public void viewIconified();

    /**
     * Called when a view is opened
     */
    public void viewOpened();
}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This code does not even compile :) Could you post the `ViewEventAdapter` code?

Comment: added code for ViewEventAdapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use 2 JFrames.

Instead the parent should be a JFrame and the child should be a non-modal JDialog. When you create the dialog you specify the frame as the parent and you get this behaviour by default.

This is the way most applications are designed.

Comment: Thanks for response. I need 2 Jframes. Is there a way to specify parent frame for frame ?

Comment: Why do you think you need 2 JFrames? If you create separate frames, then the frames should act independently of one another. If you want the windows to react together then the standard design is to use a one JFrame and the 1 or more child JDialogs. You can add any component to a JDialog just like a JFrame. When you use JFrame/JDialog together then only a single icon is displayed on the task bar so they open/close together. When using two Jframes, you get 2 icons on the task bar and you need to open/close them separately. There is no way to specify the parent because it is not standard design.

Comment: It is not a shame. The base API's should only support standard GUI design practices. Going outside the standard confuses users. Software companies like Microsoft and Apple spend millions of dollars to design efficient UI's. You can alway write your own code to do this using WindowListner's as have been suggested.

Comment: Im trying to write my own code, but im having trouble with this focus stuff!  I'm not making efficient ui, i just need to make this exact use case with 2 frames work. Can you help me?

Comment: Sorry, I only spend time on code that I might potentially use. I don't see any reason for this requirement. A JDialog can do everything a JFrame can do. The reason you create two separate JFrames is because you want the two to react independently of one another. If you want two windows to react together, then you use a JFrame/JDialog.